# Using an if function in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I'm trying to make an application to store played FIFA games.

Now I'm already able to make accounts, store games, etc. But when I'm storing a game into the DB, I would also like to store the winner and loser of the game in a way that I can use the count function later to count how many wins or losses a user has.

**Controller:**

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, exept: [:index, :show]

    def index
        @games = Game.all
    end

    def new
        @game = current_user.games.build
        @user_options = User.all.map{|u| [ u.user_name, u.id ] }
    end

    def create
        @user_options = User.all.map{|u| [ u.user_name, u.id ] }

        @game = Game.new(game_params)
        @game.home_team_user_id = current_user.id

        if @game.home_score > @game.away_score
            @game.winner_id = @game.home_team_user_id
            @game.loser_id = @game.away_team_user_id     
        else if @game.home_score < @game.away_score   
            @game.winner_id = @game.away_team_user_id
            @game.loser_id = @game.home_team_user_id  
        else
        end

        if @game.save
            redirect_to games_path, :notice => "Successfully added game!"
        else
            render 'index'
        end
    end

    def show
        @games = Game.all
    end

    def destroy
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])
        @game.destroy
        redirect_to games_path
    end

    private
    def find_game
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])    
    end

    def game_params
        params.require(:game).permit(:home_team_user_name, :home_score, :away_team_user_name, :away_score, :home_team_user_id, :away_team_user_id, :winner_id, :loser_id)
    end
end
end
```

**View:**

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center">
  <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-right:10px">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Submit New Match</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <%= simple_form_for(@game) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :home_score, :placeholder => "Your score" %>
      <%= f.text_field :away_score, :placeholder => "Your Opponents score" %> <br><br>
      <p>Opponent:</p>
      <%= f.select(:away_team_user_id, @user_options) %>
      <br> <br> <%= f.submit "Submit Match", class: "btn-submit" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this the correct way to make this calculation? Or do you have other suggestions?

If this is the correct way, then why do I get this error when I try to submit the form:

> undefined local variable or method `game_params' for

As you can see in the controller, the `game_params` is not missing. I've added an `end` at the end though, because this gave an error to load the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by:

```
else if @game.home_score < @game.away_score
```

It should be:

```
elsif @game.home_score < @game.away_score
```

Then you can remove one of the last two `end`

This was causing issues with the method beginnings/endings and conditional beginnings/endings.

Comment: No problem! We've all been there.

Answer (score 0):

Models in MVC are responsible for enforcing the business logic. So this calculation should be happening in your model - not in the controller.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...

  belongs_to :winner, class_name: 'User' # or Team or whatever
  belongs_to :loser, class_name: 'User'

  before_validation :evaluate_score!, if: -> { home_score.present? }

  private

    def evaluate_score!
      self.winner = home_score > away_score ? home_team_user : away_team_user
      self.loser = home_score < away_score ? home_team_user : away_team_user
    end
end
```

Additionally this line is inefficient:

```
@user_options = User.all.map{|u| [ u.user_name, u.id ] }
```

Since it pulls the entire records out of the DB and then loops through them in memory. You could use `@user_options = User.pluck(:username, :id)` but it is not necessary since rails has great helpers for creating inputs from collections:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:away_team_user, User.all, :id, :user_name) %>
```

Simple Form has an `association` helper method which pimps up the Rails `collection_*` helpers:

```
<%= f.association :away_team_user, collection: User.all, label_method: :user_name %>
```

- https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: I agree. Nice addition!

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll check it out!